# How can I reflect the changes that I made to my webpack.config file in Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, netlify

I have a react js project, and have made some changes to the webpack.config.js file located inside my node_modules directory. I have my project deployed on netlify but because node_modules is included in my .gitignore file, I don't have a way to reflect the changes that I made to my webpack configuration.

Edit: My package.json

```
{
  "name": "taisei-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "contentful": "^9.1.32",
    "gsap": "^3.10.4",
    "lil-gui": "^0.16.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "three": "^0.141.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0 || ^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is simply to send a pull request to the github repository of the library. Else, you can fork the repository, apply the desired changes, and write this in your package json:

```js
forked-lib": "https://github.com/<your-user-name>/forked-lib.git"
```

`forked-lib` is of course a generic name, please the replace the dummy values with proper information.

EDIT:

Sorry, I didn't see you use create react app. So, you need to eject the config files to modify them. Just run `npm eject` or `yarn eject` to do so. You will then have access to the webpack file, and it won't be ignored anymore.

Another possibility (not tested), would be to change your `.gitignore` file by excluding all node modules except webpack:

`/node_modules\/(?!webpack$)/`

But I'm not sure it will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

But webpack is not defined in package.json (see updated question).

Kindly advise back.